# Disable EJB Scuduler in docker swarm replication app

Tags: java, docker, jakarta-ee, docker-swarm, payara

i'm using docker swarm to deploy my application.
I'm using `payara` image (payara/server-full:4.181).
Docker version `18.03.1-ce`, build `9ee9f40`

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: always
    build: ./../yf-services
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/yf-services
    entrypoint: "/opt/payara41/bin/startInForeground.sh --passwordfile=/opt/pwdfile -d --postbootcommandfile glassfish/domains/domain1"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
networks:
  nginx-proxy:
```

is it possible to disable `EJB` scheduler in replicated application?
Is it possible to pass some environment variable to replicated application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some workaround solution, maybe someone will find better one ...

in service you could pass env variable

```
environment:
  - TASK_NAME={{.Task.Name}}
```

where .Task.Name will be your stackName_serviceName.number
in my case it was for each replica

```
yf_backend.1.....
yf_backend.2.....
```

then from you JAVA app you can get env variable and check a number of replica. 
Leave it enabled for 1 and for the rest disabled.
Something like this:

```
public boolean isEnvVariableEnableScheduler() {
    final String envSchedulerTaskEnvVeriable = System.getenv("TASK_NAME");
    return envSchedulerTaskEnvVeriable == null || envSchedulerTaskEnvVeriable.contains("yf_backend.1");

}
```